# MySql Insert from Select issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small shopping cart with an option to create lists of products that you can use later for fast checkout.
The addListToCart function adds a created product list to a shopping cart. 
The addListToCart function works only for one list. If you want to insert another list of products to the cart it doesn'tm and no error.
How can I fix this?

```
  function addListToCart($list){
    global $mysql;
    $idCart = $this->idCart();
    $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $cod = $this->getCodProdus($produs);
    $titlu = $this->getNumeProdus($produs);
    $prettotal = $this->getPretProdus($produs);
    $pretunitar = $this->getPretUnitar($produs);
    $pretredus = $this->getPretRedus($produs);
    $gramaj = $this->getGramaj($produs);
    $tva = $this->getTVA($produs);

    if($idCart == 0){
        $idCos = $mysql->insert(sprintf("INSERT INTO cosuri SET status = 'open', 
                                                     phpsessid = '%s', 
                                                     uid = '%d', 
                                                     data = '%s'", 
                                                     $this->phpid,
                                                     $this->uid,
                                                     $data));

        $mysql->insert(sprintf("INSERT INTO comenzi (produs, 
                                                     titlu,
                                                     cantitate,
                                                     prettotal,
                                                     pretunitar,
                                                     pretredus,
                                                     gramaj,
                                                     tva,
                                                     data,
                                                     cos,
                                                     cod) 
                                SELECT p.id, 
                                       p.titlu, 
                                       lgp.cantitate, 
                                       p.prettotal, 
                                       p.pretunitar, 
                                       p.pretredus, 
                                       p.gramaj, 
                                       p.tva, 
                                       now(), 
                                       '%d',
                                       lgp.product_code 
                                FROM produse p
                                LEFT JOIN list_group_products lgp on p.cod=lgp.product_code
                                WHERE group_id='%d' AND p.vizibil=1", $idCos, $list));

    }else{

        $mysql->insert(sprintf("INSERT INTO comenzi (produs, 
                                                     titlu,
                                                     cantitate,
                                                     prettotal,
                                                     pretunitar,
                                                     pretredus,
                                                     gramaj,
                                                     tva,
                                                     data,
                                                     cos,
                                                     cod)  
                                SELECT p.id, 
                                       p.titlu, 
                                       lgp.cantitate, 
                                       p.prettotal, 
                                       p.pretunitar, 
                                       p.pretredus, 
                                       p.gramaj, 
                                       p.tva, 
                                       now(), 
                                       '%d',
                                       lgp.product_code
                                FROM produse p
                                LEFT JOIN list_group_products lgp on p.cod=lgp.product_code
                                LEFT JOIN comenzi c on p.cod=c.cod
                                WHERE c.cos='%d' AND lgp.group_id='%d' AND p.vizibil=1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cantitate = c.cantitate + 1", $idCart, $idCart, $list));

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you actually describe the problem, all you've said at the moment is it was working until you changed it, but you've not told us how you changed it or what is wrong with it now that is causing you problems.

Comment: The addListToCart function works only for one list. If you want to insert another list of products to the cart it doesn't...no error

Comment: I think the problem is the WHERE c.cos='%s'

Comment: Why are you using `%d` and then `%s` for the same value in your last `sprintf`? Besides, is `$idCart` an integer or a string?

Comment: Is an int. I fixed it